# what does onBackPress call in a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, onresume, onpause

In a Fragment i have this:

```
onPause(){

super.onPause();
if(flag){
getActivity.finish();
}else{
}
}

onResume(){

flag = true;
super.onResume();
}
```

and there is a Button, on click i set this flag to false:

```
Button.onClick{
flag = false;
}
```

The idea is:

when the **button** is clicked don't finish this Activity. But when device **BackButton** is pressed finish().

But this logic isn't working. The reason is, when i press **BackButton** of the device, **onPause** is not being called.

This is the 4th Fragment in the Activty. So when i press BackButton i can see the 3rd Fragment. Which i don't want to.

**I am using this on a API 10 device, But my application uses support library v4.**

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to close the activity on the back press, then Override the `onBackPressed` inside the **activity** as following:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourfragment");
   if (fragment instanceOf YourFragmet) {
          finish();
          return;
   }
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

If you want to close the activity on the button click, then you can call

```
Button.onClick{
  getActivity().onBackPressed();
}
```

OR

```
Button.onClick{
  getActivity().finish();
}
```

If When you are transitioning between Fragments, you call addToBackStack() as part of your FragmentTransaction, then the back button will take you to the fragment on the top of the back stack

Comment: No. I **don't** want to close the Activity **onButtonClicked**. I want to close the Activity only when **BackIsPressed**

Comment: Should i use this in **onViewCreated()**?? with **fragment.getView** replaced with the **view** parameter of **onViewCreated**

Comment: No its not reaching this code when backPressed.Is there any specific block i must use this in. Like **onCreateView** or something else;

Comment: There is nothing like **onBackPressed** to override. May be because i am using targerAPI = 15; But when device back is pressed, Fragment's onPause() must be triggered right?

Comment: onBackPressed in the activity not the fragment

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you use onDetach() of Fragment? On Back key pressed, there will be onDetach() called on the fragment to remove that.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
   super.onDetach();
   if(flag){
     getActivity.finish();
   }else{
        }
}
```

Comment: When is `onDetach()` called? on backstack popup??

Comment: yes, when you press backkey the foreground fragment will get detached and the previously attached fragment will get displayed.