# Send a bundle while using fragment transaction

Tags: android, fragment

I am using this to add a Fragment to the Activity:

```
FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
t.add(R.id.frame, new FeedListFragment());
t.commit();
```

This fragment is a SideMenu. There is an Image in this Fragment which i want to check whether it is changed and replace it with new image. I what this check in `onPause();`

But the fragment's `onPause` or `onResume` are not triggered as expected.

[Fragment onResume() & onPause() is not called on backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326155/fragment-onresume-onpause-is-not-called-on-backstack)

Even i asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758597/what-does-onbackpress-call-in-a-fragment) on sof regarding this, but could not get an Answer.

But the actual question is:

How can i send some data/bundle to this fragment in the `onResume()` of the MainActivity and Track that in the Fragment Added?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From fragment, use `onAttach()` of fragment, to register parent activity with fragment. Once Fragment has a handle on Activity, it can call its methods.

From Activity, use Fragment manager to `find` the fragment by its tag name, and call its methods.